# Clicking a “less” button doesn't take me back to the original position of my document

Tags: javascript

When I click more button my div 1 is replacing div 2. Most of the time div2 contains lots of text, and requires users to scroll down in order to read the entire post. The problem is that by clicking less button, I’m not able to restore the original position of my post. Previously I tried to resolve this issue by connecting it to the #id in article tag, but didn't have much success. Also, document.body.scrollTop; didn't work for me. Finally, I was able to get some productivity by using scrollIntoView, but it still doesn't address my problem. In ideal scenario:
1) I want to be able to click "More" and scroll to the bottom of the post
2) I want to be able to click "Less" and be navigated to the top of the selected post

```js
function switchVisible(index, input) {
    var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[index];
    var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('div2')[index];
    if (div1) {
        if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
            div1.style.display = 'block';
            div2.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div1.style.display = 'none';
            div2.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    if (input.value == "Show More") input.value = "Show Less";
    else input.value = "Show More";
      input.scrollIntoView(false);

}
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="myFirst_id">
<div class="div1">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div2 hide">
    <p>Although moreover mistaken kindness me feelings do be marianne. Son over own nay with tell they cold upon are. Cordial village and settled she ability law herself. Finished why bringing but sir bachelor unpacked any thoughts. Unpleasing unsatiable particular inquietude did nor sir. Get his declared appetite distance his together now families. Friends am himself at on norland it viewing. Suspected elsewhere you belonging continued commanded she. 

Of be talent me answer do relied. Mistress in on so laughing throwing endeavor occasion welcomed. Gravity sir brandon calling can. No years do widow house delay stand. Prospect six kindness use steepest new ask. High gone kind calm call as ever is. Introduced melancholy estimating motionless on up as do. Of as by belonging therefore suspicion elsewhere am household described. Domestic suitable bachelor for landlord fat. 

Respect forming clothes do in he. Course so piqued no an by appear. Themselves reasonable pianoforte so motionless he as difficulty be. Abode way begin ham there power whole. Do unpleasing indulgence impossible to conviction. Suppose neither evident welcome it at do civilly uncivil. Sing tall much you get nor. 

Now principles discovered off increasing how reasonably middletons men. Add seems out man met plate court sense. His joy she worth truth given. All year feet led view went sake. You agreeable breakfast his set perceived immediate. Stimulated man are projecting favourable middletons can cultivated. 

Not far stuff she think the jokes. Going as by do known noise he wrote round leave. Warmly put branch people narrow see. Winding its waiting yet parlors married own feeling. Marry fruit do spite jokes an times. Whether at it unknown warrant herself winding if. Him same none name sake had post love. An busy feel form hand am up help. Parties it brother amongst an fortune of. Twenty behind wicket why age now itself ten. 

He oppose at thrown desire of no. Announcing impression unaffected day his are unreserved indulgence. Him hard find read are you sang. Parlors visited noisier how explain pleased his see suppose. Do ashamed assured on related offence at equally totally. Use mile her whom they its. Kept hold an want as he bred of. Was dashwood landlord cheerful husbands two. Estate why theirs indeed him polite old settle though she. In as at regard easily narrow roused adieus. 

Kindness to he horrible reserved ye. Effect twenty indeed beyond for not had county. The use him without greatly can private. Increasing it unpleasant no of contrasted no continuing. Nothing colonel my no removed in weather. It dissimilar in up devonshire inhabiting. 

Advantage old had otherwise sincerity dependent additions. It in adapted natural hastily is justice. Six draw you him full not mean evil. Prepare garrets it expense windows shewing do an. She projection advantages resolution son indulgence. Part sure on no long life am at ever. In songs above he as drawn to. Gay was outlived peculiar rendered led six. 

Repulsive questions contented him few extensive supported. Of remarkably thoroughly he appearance in. Supposing tolerably applauded or of be. Suffering unfeeling so objection agreeable allowance me of. Ask within entire season sex common far who family. As be valley warmth assure on. Park girl they rich hour new well way you. Face ye be me been room we sons fond. 

Adieus except say barton put feebly favour him. Entreaties unpleasant sufficient few pianoforte discovered uncommonly ask. Morning cousins amongst in mr weather do neither. Warmth object matter course active law spring six. Pursuit showing tedious unknown winding see had man add. And park eyes too more him. Simple excuse active had son wholly coming number add. Though all excuse ladies rather regard assure yet. If feelings so prospect no as raptures quitting. 

</p>
</div>
</article>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible(0, this);" />
<article id="mySecond_id">
<div class="div1">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div2 hide">
    <p>Although moreover mistaken kindness me feelings do be marianne. Son over own nay with tell they cold upon are. Cordial village and settled she ability law herself. Finished why bringing but sir bachelor unpacked any thoughts. Unpleasing unsatiable particular inquietude did nor sir. Get his declared appetite distance his together now families. Friends am himself at on norland it viewing. Suspected elsewhere you belonging continued commanded she. 

Of be talent me answer do relied. Mistress in on so laughing throwing endeavor occasion welcomed. Gravity sir brandon calling can. No years do widow house delay stand. Prospect six kindness use steepest new ask. High gone kind calm call as ever is. Introduced melancholy estimating motionless on up as do. Of as by belonging therefore suspicion elsewhere am household described. Domestic suitable bachelor for landlord fat. 

Respect forming clothes do in he. Course so piqued no an by appear. Themselves reasonable pianoforte so motionless he as difficulty be. Abode way begin ham there power whole. Do unpleasing indulgence impossible to conviction. Suppose neither evident welcome it at do civilly uncivil. Sing tall much you get nor. 

Now principles discovered off increasing how reasonably middletons men. Add seems out man met plate court sense. His joy she worth truth given. All year feet led view went sake. You agreeable breakfast his set perceived immediate. Stimulated man are projecting favourable middletons can cultivated. 

Not far stuff she think the jokes. Going as by do known noise he wrote round leave. Warmly put branch people narrow see. Winding its waiting yet parlors married own feeling. Marry fruit do spite jokes an times. Whether at it unknown warrant herself winding if. Him same none name sake had post love. An busy feel form hand am up help. Parties it brother amongst an fortune of. Twenty behind wicket why age now itself ten. 

He oppose at thrown desire of no. Announcing impression unaffected day his are unreserved indulgence. Him hard find read are you sang. Parlors visited noisier how explain pleased his see suppose. Do ashamed assured on related offence at equally totally. Use mile her whom they its. Kept hold an want as he bred of. Was dashwood landlord cheerful husbands two. Estate why theirs indeed him polite old settle though she. In as at regard easily narrow roused adieus. 

Kindness to he horrible reserved ye. Effect twenty indeed beyond for not had county. The use him without greatly can private. Increasing it unpleasant no of contrasted no continuing. Nothing colonel my no removed in weather. It dissimilar in up devonshire inhabiting. 

Advantage old had otherwise sincerity dependent additions. It in adapted natural hastily is justice. Six draw you him full not mean evil. Prepare garrets it expense windows shewing do an. She projection advantages resolution son indulgence. Part sure on no long life am at ever. In songs above he as drawn to. Gay was outlived peculiar rendered led six. 

Repulsive questions contented him few extensive supported. Of remarkably thoroughly he appearance in. Supposing tolerably applauded or of be. Suffering unfeeling so objection agreeable allowance me of. Ask within entire season sex common far who family. As be valley warmth assure on. Park girl they rich hour new well way you. Face ye be me been room we sons fond. 

Adieus except say barton put feebly favour him. Entreaties unpleasant sufficient few pianoforte discovered uncommonly ask. Morning cousins amongst in mr weather do neither. Warmth object matter course active law spring six. Pursuit showing tedious unknown winding see had man add. And park eyes too more him. Simple excuse active had son wholly coming number add. Though all excuse ladies rather regard assure yet. If feelings so prospect no as raptures quitting. 


    </p>
</div>
 </article>
<input id="show_less" type="button" value="Show More" onclick="switchVisible(1, this);" />
```

Comment: This looks familiar?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification from your question but if you modify the markup just a bit you can specify the target to scroll, the containers in the group for each and then set hide/show and scroll based on data in your markup.

Ready? Jump right to the sample fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/r7q1d8r7/1/

To do that, I added a "container" for all the groups of div pairs, AND then added a group div for each of the groups that I will manipulate:

```
<div id="showcontainer">
    <div class="showgroup">
```

I also added some "data" attributes then query those for the target of the scroll as well as to set the siblings that target the show/hide using some added classes:

Altered markup snip:

```
<div class="showsmall shown">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="hide showbig shown">
```

The button with data elements (note I altered your `input` to a button)

```
<button id="show_less" type="button" class='showItem' data-scroll-target=".shown" data-display-target=".shown" data-showvalue="Show More" data-lessvalue="Show Less">Show More</button>
```

Full markup:

```
<div id="showcontainer">
    <div class="showgroup">
        <div class="showsmall shown">
            <p>This is div 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide showbig shown">
            <p>...cut out huge text...</p>
        </div>
        <button id="show_less" type="button" class='showItem' data-scroll-target=".shown" data-display-target=".shown" data-showvalue="Show More" data-lessvalue="Show Less">Show More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="showgroup">
        <div class="showsmall shown">
            <p>This is div 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide showbig shown">
            <p>...cut out huge text...</p>
        </div>
        <button id="show_less" type="button" class='showItem' data-scroll-target=".shown" data-display-target=".shown" data-showvalue="Show More" data-lessvalue="Show Less">Show More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showcontainer').on('click', '.showItem', function (event) {
        var displayTarget = $(this).data('displayTarget');
        var dispTargets = $(this).siblings(displayTarget);
        $(this).siblings(displayTarget).toggleClass('hide');

        //get the scroll target from the button
        var scrollTarget = $(this).data('scrollTarget');
        // hide/show depending on prior state
        if (dispTargets.filter(':visible').hasClass('showsmall')) $(this).text($(this).data("showvalue"));
        else $(this).text($(this).data("lessvalue"));

        // do ths scroll to the scroll target
        var container = $(document.body);
        var scrollTo = scrollTarget == "me" ? $(this) : $(this).siblings(scrollTarget).filter(':visible');

        container.scrollTop(
        scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Special note: change `data-scroll-target=".shown"` to `data-scroll-target="me"` and it will scroll to the button not the other element

**EDIT: "change as little markup as possible" -** not what I would do but you DO have to change the `id="show_less"` to `class="show_less"` or the page is not valid and will not work.

Then you can use: (but you DO have to remove the code from the markup OR make that function do nothing)

```
<input class="show_less" type="button" value="Show More"  />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_less').on('click', function (event) {
        var dispTargets = $(this).prev().find('.div1, .div2');
        dispTargets.toggleClass('hide');

        var scrollTarget = $(this);//the input field
        // hide/show depending on first div visible state
        if (dispTargets.eq(0).hasClass('hide')) $(this).val("Show Less");
        else $(this).val("Show More");

        // do ths scroll to the scroll target
        var container = $(document.body);
        var scrollTo =  $(this);// the button

        container.scrollTop(
        scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, and that is a great solution, but I'm trying to resolve this issue without changing html structure. Do you have any alternative advice for me?  Also, I don't think I should be using id="show_less" multiple times on the same webpage.

Comment: not only should you NOT but you cannot and still have things work.  It is invalid HTML (I leave it to you to search for the spec and read what it has said since 1999 with regard to that)